# eclipse: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I'm working on javacv project but every time I try to declare a matrix as below:

```
Mat trainingData = new Mat();
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:447)
```

And when i search for a solution, i always found that i have to add:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

But i'm always having the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown at runtime when an application attempts to load a native library and that library does not exist.

It sounds like something went wrong when attaching your library or your library was not set up correctly in your IDE.

See: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse

Comment: My fault was that I was not naming the folder in C:/ as the user library name. But now, it works perfectly. Thanks!!